# how to check a string contain in an array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi I want to check if a string is contained on an array of objects. I've tried some methods like `indexOf` or `data.filter`, but I can't find  a better solution. My array looks like:

```
  0 [   {
    "date": "12/19/2014 12:00:00 AM",
    "type": "red",
     "name": "hert",
     "to": "418",
      "newitem": [
      {   
        "new": "gt",
        "level": "typeone",}]
}]
```

I want to know if the string "typeone" is inside the 0[] array.

I've tried try :

```
var result = $.grep(data[0].newitem, function(e){ return e.level =="typeone"; });
```

but I didn't get the answer.

Comment: Your question is not clear and accurate! You want to know the type of an array or the type of the item in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data[0].newitem.filter((e) => {return e.level == 'typeone'}).length
```

`if length > 1`  //string is present

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `Array.some`([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

```
var result = data[0].newItem.some(function(obj) { return obj.level === 'typeone'})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return true/false

```
var result = $.grep(data[0].newitem, function(e){ return e.level =="typeone"; }).length>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the nested string from that object you are looking at doing this.

```
data[0].newitem[0].level
```

this will equal "typeone"

Your question is unclear. Another tip is to check the type of data with

```
//returns boolean
typeof Object === 'undefined'
typeof Object === 'Array'
typeof Object === 'String'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var arr = [{
 "date": "12/19/2014 12:00:00 AM",
 "type": "red",
 "name": "hert",
 "to": "418",
 "newitem": [
 {
  "new": "gt",
  "level": "typeone"
 }]
}];

console.log(containsString(arr, "typeone")); // contains "typeone"  --> true     

function containsString(arr, strSearch) {
 var same = false;
 for (var p in arr) {
  var entry = arr[p];
  var type = toString.call(entry);    
  
  if (type.indexOf("Object") > -1 ? true : type.indexOf("Array") > -1 ? true : false) {
   return containsString(entry, strSearch);
  } else {
   same = (entry === strSearch);
   if (same) return same;
  }
 } // end for loop
 return same;
}// end iterate
```